# Correct python Regular expression to create double dict

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of files with names name_x01_y01_000.h5 or name_y01_x01_000.h5

What is the correct regular expression (or other method) to create a list of:
file, x_ind, y_ind

So far i have this code:

```
name = 'S3_FullBrain_Mosaic_'
type = '.h5'

wildc = name + '*' + type
files = glob.glob(wildc)
files = np.asarray(files)

wildre = 'r\"' +name+'x(?P<x_ind>\d+)_y(?P<y_ind>\d+).+\"'
m = re.match(wildre,files)
```

Comment: You can't use raw string literals like that. Just say `name + r'...'`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the glob already ensures the correct filename and extension, the regex need only match the indices. `re.search` allows a partial match. `.groupdict` creates a dictionary with named groups as keys. The `file` key can be handled manually.

```
>>> file = 'S3_FullBrain_Mosaic_x02_y05_abcd.h5'
>>> result = re.search(r'x(?P<x_ind>\d+)_y(?P<y_ind>\d+)', file).groupdict()
>>> result
{'y_ind': '05', 'x_ind': '02'}
>>> result['file'] = file
>>> result
{'y_ind': '05', 'file': 'S3_FullBrain_Mosaic_x02_y05_abcd.h5', 'x_ind': '02'}
```

You can iterate over the files to produce the list of dicts. For this there's no need to create a numpy array, since I doubt you're going to do any heavy numerical calculations on the `files` list.

To handle both possible formats you will need to call `re.search` with two regexes. One will return `None`, the other a match on which you can use `groupdict`.

Comment: It doesn't cover `name_y01_x01_000.h5` case.

Comment: Did you test your edited regex? I am not sure it would work with subgroup name being used multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.findall`

```
import re

names = ['name_x01_y01_000.h5', 'name_y01_x01_000.h5']
for name in names:
    matches = re.findall(r'_([xy])(\d+)(?=_)', name)
    d = {k: int(v) for k, v in matches}
    d['name'] = name
```